# Unable to open google in android emulator's browser

Tags: android, proxy

I am unable to open google in my android emulator.
  i have set the proxy 
       in debug configuration...--> application--> target tab--?aditional emulator command line options(-http-proxy  http://:/)

still i am not open google in my emulator

help me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu->settings->wireless&networks->MobileNetworks->AccessPoinNames->Telkila->proxy(your system ip address) and port(8080) ->save it

now you can work with internet